# SQL and BigQuery fields selections

Tags: google-bigquery

Following shorten code requests the table and outputs table schema:

```
# pip install google-cloud-bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("chicago_crime", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("crime")
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
table.schema[:4]
```

output:

```
[SchemaField('unique_key', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED', 'Unique identifier for the record.', ()),
 SchemaField('case_number', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', 'The Chicago Police Department RD Number (Records Division Number), which is unique to the incident.', ()),
 SchemaField('date', 'TIMESTAMP', 'NULLABLE', 'Date when the incident occurred. this is sometimes a best estimate.', ()),
 SchemaField('block', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', 'The partially redacted address where the incident occurred, placing it on the same block as the actual address.', ())
```

The code which lists fields (1,3) is following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
fields_list=itemgetter(1,3)(table.schema)
client.list_rows(table, selected_fields=fields_list, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
```

output:

```
    case_number block
0   JC299491    114XX S CHAMPLAIN AVE
1   JC273204    053XX N LOWELL AVE
```

How to indicate explicitly the name of fields, something like that?

```
fields_list=['case_number', 'block']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a reverse-map of schema fieldnames to their respective `SchemaField` objects.

Something like:

```
schema_fields = dict((s.name.lower(), s) for s in table.schema)
```

With this, you can cherry-pick field with their names:

```
fields_list = ['case_number', 'block']
selected_fields = map(lambda n: schema_fields[n], fields_list)
client.list_rows(table, selected_fields=selected_fields, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
```

Comment: It works. All attributes for google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaFields are explained here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html